# rsync transfer speed: same country vs other country

Tags: networking

Does proximity of one server to another affect the overall transfer speed on a large number of small files?

Say I have a server with a million small files in Germany, would it be considerably faster to transfer them (using rsync) to another server in Germany vs, say, Finland? Or it only affects latency?

Comment: Server means computer it can be fast or slow in same country as well. So latency plus the server system(like hardware read/write speed, wan/lan) can affect transfer speed, since it is all about file transfer with verification. Though I'm noob in linux, so can't say more, wait for someone who have more details knowledge about that.

Comment: [rsync is latency-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014501/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-transfer-files-over-high-latency-and-high-bandwidth-l) and runs over TCP, so yes, unlike some other file transfer solutions, rsync transfer speed can be more affected by server distance depending on your connection speed. In practice though, the latency might not be enough for it to matter.

Comment: Servers within a data centre in the EU to another EU country are generally capable of transfers in excess of 100gbit+ and the latency between data centres are generally in the sub 10 ms mark, so the limitations will be purely down to the servers that you are using. If transferring hundreds of thousands of small files then the most important factor is your I/O performance, making SSD hosting advisable and cloud hosting as a preferred option.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister thanks, did not know that. But is it a limitation of rsync that can be worked around with another software?

Comment: @SimonHayter, thanks, both servers will be on ssd, I guess it would still make sense to go for the lower physical distance since I'm all about that speed, and it seems like rsync doesn't like latency